# Prevent < > parsing tinymce to &gt

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I do not have HTML content in it, but regular string which has text like

```
 <some data>, <some text>
```

it is being saved as `some data&gt;`

How do I save it exactly like this `<some data>`. I need to use this data somewhere else where it should match exactly like this, but its already encoded. I have already tried using entity_encoding: 'raw' and encoding: 'xml'. But they still end up encoding before saving. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters **have** to be encoded when part of HTML since the `<` and `>` have special meaning in HTML.

There are a variety of characters that have to be encoded per the specification and these are two of them.